# Unable to get Firebase Realtime DB to configure with my web project. Writes do not show up

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I cannot seem to configure the realtime database to my react native app correctly.

- I have already set up the project on firebase.
- I added a "web app".
- I checked and it seems like my permissions allow read/write.
- I copied the config file
- installed firebase with npm

Unfortunately, an write attempts to the database do not seem to show up. I am not quite sure if it is because I did not configure the app correctly or if the code I used to set up writes is wrong

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "VizboMobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

In a file called firebaseConfig.tsx, I have the following:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "aaaaaaaaaa",
    authDomain: "bbbbbbbbbb",
    databaseURL: "cccccccccc",
    projectId: "dddddddddd",
    storageBucket: "eeeeeeeeeee",
    messagingSenderId: "ffffffff",
    appId: "gggggggggg",
    measurementId: "hhhhhhhhhhh"
};

const app3 = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)


export {app3};
```

Following this, I used the following code to attempt to write to the database I created:

```
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import {set,ref} from 'firebase/database'
const db = getDatabase(app3)

function writeUserData(userId, name, email) {
  set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
  username: name,
  email: email

});
}
```

I then have a button activate like so:

```
function TestFirebaseScreen({navigation}: any) {
  function writeUserData(userId: string, name: string, email: string) {
    
    set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
      username: name,
      email: email,
    }).then(() => console.log("success"))

  }

    return (
      <SafeAreaView>            
        <Button  
          title = "test"
          onPress={() => writeUserData("abc", "a", "b")}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default TestFirebaseScreen
```

When viewing my database on firebase, the database is still empty. Can anyone provide any insight on why this is happening?

[image: here is a snippet of the rules on my console]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full file of `firebaseConfig.tsx` and the code block that follows it with all relevant imports. It currently does not look like you are importing `app3` before passing it to `getDatabase` which may be the problem.

Comment: Additionally, you are starting asynchronous tasks (like `set(someRef, someData)`) without listening to errors using `.catch((err) => /* do something on error */)`.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, but it's hard to say what's going on when you run it. I recommend setting a breakpoint on the call to the database, running in the debugger until you hit that breakpoint, and then checking the values of each variable to see if it matches what you expect. If it does, step through the code line by line until you spot a place where it doesn't match your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, the most common newbie mistake with db writes in Firebase is misconfigured permission rules.

By default, all write operations are forbidden. You must explicitly set the permission in a database.rules.json file.

Something as simple as the following will do:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Consider reading the documentation on how to write proper rules for your project though.

Unfortunately, your rules config is the only critical piece of code in your question. You probably should edit your question to add that missing piece of information.

Don't forget to publish your new rules through firebase cli. Just having the file around won't make any difference until properly published.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. I did edit my question and included what the rules were as seen on the console. It seems to be what you have there. From the documentation, it seems as though I can just modify the rules via the console instead of including a file. Did I get this right? Or do I still need to add another json file for the rules?

Comment: Indeed, you can simply tweak the rules in the console if that method suits your workflow.
I don't have anymore ideas for the debugging now though.
Do you see anything in the console that would tell something went wrong ? Is your console.log statement triggered ?

You could try setting some data mannually in your db and try to query it. That would give you more insights on your setup. If it fails as well, something is off higher in the process.